# type coercion between string and number

Tags: javascript

I'm little confused with my NOOP question here:

If a string and a number are compared, the string will be cast to an integer:

```
"1"==1 //true
```

Operating with string and a number, the number will be cast to a string:

```
"1"+1 // '11"
```

Why there is so difference in javascript between type coercion?

Comment: add more fun: `"1"===1`

Comment: @epascarello yes that fails to compare but I'm not talking to strictly comparing but type coercing...

Comment: Plenty of dupes on this, trying to find one. But your answer is in the explaination for `==` on [MDN Equality Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators)

Comment: to use number in js as a number, add a + right next to it. `+1 + +1 ==2`

Comment: That's just how the operators are defined. Are you asking what the reasoning is behind that decision? Because only people working on the spec or Brendan Eich can answer that.

Comment: @Banana I'm not talking about string to number (I know that obviously) but talking about type coercion....

Comment: @epascarello I tried to find dup question here, but couldn't find so, asked to know a little more about type coercion

Comment: Misunderstanding *Concatenation*, *Addition*, *Comparison*, *Equality*, *Strict Equality*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how the operators are defined (http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3, http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1).

- With `==`, if one operand is a string and the other is a number, the string is converted to a number.
- With `+`, if one operand is a string, the other one is converted to a string.

So the difference is which operand is converted to which type, which is different for each operand (e.g. with multiplication, both operands are converted to numbers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would be very glad to know why differences out there? (the key reason)

Comment: That's something probably only Brendan Eich can answer. You could also ask at http://esdiscuss.org/. Questions like this are usually not suited for Stack Overflow since only a extreme small audience (a single person in the worst case) can answer them. However, feel free to add your answer after you get it from Brendan or the list.